# ora-00936 missing expression with insert into clause

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Getting ORA-00936: missing expression in the following query.
Please help.

```
INSERT INTO TT_FX_LADDER_INFO(DEAL_NUM,SPOT_RATE,FORWARD_RATE,LBS_RATE,DF_CCY1,DF_CCY2,FX_TYPE,TYPE,TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM,ENTITY_FBO_ID_NUM,POS_CCY_PAIR,AS_ON_DATE,DECOMPOSE_DATE,CCY_ONE_AMOUNT,CCY_TWO_AMOUNT,CCY_1,CCY_2,IS_FX_MERCHANT_TRADE) VALUES  
(
    SELECT '0','0','0','0','0','0','FWD','OPENING POSITION',TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM,ENTITY_FBO_ID_NUM,CURRENCY_PAIR,LADDER_DATE,DECOMPOSE_DATE,SUM(CCY_ONE_AMOUNT) CCY_ONE_POSITION,SUM(CCY_TWO_AMOUNT) CCY_TWO_POSITION,CCY_1,CCY_2,IS_FX_MERCHANT_TRADE 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT hdg.TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM,hdg.ENTITY_FBO_ID_NUM,hdg.CURRENCY_PAIR,
        TO_CHAR(elem.LADDER_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') LADDER_DATE,
        TO_CHAR(elem.LADDER_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') DECOMPOSE_DATE

        FROM TT_FX_HDG hdg,TT_FX_HDG_ELEMS elem
        WHERE elem.DEAL_NUM = hdg.DEAL_NUM 
        AND hdg.FX_TYPE = 'FWD'   

    )
    group by TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM,ENTITY_FBO_ID_NUM,CURRENCY_PAIR,LADDER_DATE,DECOMPOSE_DATE,CCY_1,CCY_2,IS_FX_MERCHANT_TRADE
);
```

Inner query without insert into clause works fine.

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Kindly format your query nicely.

Comment: Please format , extremely harmful to eyes :D

Comment: can u share your table schema so that I can debug it on my local

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `values`.  There is no need when using `insert . . . select`.  So, assuming everything else lines up:

```
INSERT INTO TT_FX_LADDER_INFO(DEAL_NUM, SPOT_RATE,FORWARD_RATE,LBS_RATE,DF_CCY1,DF_CCY2,FX_TYPE,TYPE,TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM,ENTITY_FBO_ID_NUM,POS_CCY_PAIR,AS_ON_DATE,DECOMPOSE_DATE,CCY_ONE_AMOUNT,CCY_TWO_AMOUNT,CCY_1,CCY_2,IS_FX_MERCHANT_TRADE
                              )  
    SELECT '0','0','0','0','0','0', 'FWD', 'OPENING POSITION',
           TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM, ENTITY_FBO_ID_NUM, CURRENCY_PAIR,
           LADDER_DATE, DECOMPOSE_DATE,
           SUM(CCY_ONE_AMOUNT) as CCY_ONE_POSITION,
           SUM(CCY_TWO_AMOUNT) as CCY_TWO_POSITION,
           CCY_1,CCY_2,IS_FX_MERCHANT_TRADE 
    FROM (SELECT hdg.TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM, hdg.ENTITY_FBO_ID_NUM, hdg.CURRENCY_PAIR,
                 TO_CHAR(elem.LADDER_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') as LADDER_DATE,
                 TO_CHAR(elem.LADDER_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') as DECOMPOSE_DATE
          FROM TT_FX_HDG hdg JOIN
               TT_FX_HDG_ELEMS elem
               ON elem.DEAL_NUM = hdg.DEAL_NUM  AND hdg.FX_TYPE = 'FWD'   
          ) x
     GROUP BY TRADING_BOOK_FBO_ID_NUM, ENTITY_FBO_ID_NUM, CURRENCY_PAIR,
              LADDER_DATE, DECOMPOSE_DATE, CCY_1,CCY_2,
              IS_FX_MERCHANT_TRADE;
```

I would also suggest:

- Write your queries so you can read them -- break up impossibly long lines and uses spaces after commas.
- Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Do not put single quotes around numeric constants.  In some contexts (although not here), this can lead to performance problems.
- Use `as` when defining column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is altogether wrong. Found some errors.

```
SUM(CCY_ONE_AMOUNT) CCY_ONE_POSITION,SUM(CCY_TWO_AMOUNT) CCY_TWO_POSITION,CCY_1,CCY_2,IS_FX_MERCHANT_TRADE
```

Above columns are not selected in the inner select statement. Hence it will not work.